# Data is not displayed for some ID from the procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a stored procedure which brings all the data created by a particular users. So if a user with name `A` has created 100 records and when I run this procedure it should bring 100 records.

Currently it is not bringing all those 100 records, some of them are missing and I am unable to find out why it's like that.

Below is my stored procedure.

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE CHANGEREQUESTS_CREATED_GETLIST
(
  P_USERNAME in CHANGEREQUESTS.CREATEDBY%type
, P_JOBID IN CLOB--VARCHAR2
, P_PAGENO IN NUMBER
, P_PAGESIZE IN NUMBER
, TOTALCOUNT OUT NUMBER
, OUTPUTTABLE OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS 

  START_RECORD_NO NUMBER := 1;
  END_RECORD_NO   NUMBER := 10;
BEGIN

  IF P_PAGENO IS NOT NULL AND P_PAGESIZE IS NOT NULL THEN
    START_RECORD_NO := ((P_PAGENO -1) * P_PAGESIZE) +1;
    END_RECORD_NO := P_PAGESIZE * P_PAGENO;
  END IF;
    
  --open TOTALCOUNT for
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO TOTALCOUNT 
  FROM  
      CHANGEREQUESTS CR
  where
   EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM THE ( SELECT CAST( STR2TBL( P_JOBID ) AS MYTABLETYPE ) FROM DUAL ) TT WHERE TT.COLUMN_VALUE = CR.JOBID )
      --CR.JOBID in (select REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_JOBID,'[^,]+', 1, level) from DUAL connect by REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_JOBID, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
      and CREATEDBY = P_USERNAME
      and JOBID > 0;
          
  OPEN OUTPUTTABLE FOR 
  select 
     CHANGEREQUESTID
    ,DESCRIPTION 
    ,CHANGEREQUESTNUMBER
    ,STATENAME
    ,CITYNAME
    ,CATEGORY
    ,CHANGETYPE
    ,STATUSID
    ,CREATEDBY
    ,OPENCLOSED
    ,JOBID
    ,CREATEDON
    ,LASTMODIFIEDON
  from
  (   select 
       ROW_NUMBER() over ( order by CR.CHANGEREQUESTID DESC) ROWNO
      ,CR.CHANGEREQUESTID
      ,CR.DESCRIPTION 
      ,CR.CHANGEREQUESTNUMBER
      ,CR.STATENAME
      ,CR.CITYNAME
      ,CC.CATEGORY
      ,CT.CHANGETYPE
      ,CR.STATUSID
      ,CR.CREATEDBY
      ,'' as OPENCLOSED
      ,CR.JOBID
      ,CR.CREATEDON
      ,CR.LASTMODIFIEDON
      FROM  
        CHANGEREQUESTS CR
          inner join
        CHANGETYPES CT
          on CR.CHANGETYPEID = CT.CHANGETYPEID
          inner join 
        CHANGECATEGORIES CC
          ON CC.CHANGECATEGORYID = CT.CHANGECATEGORYID
      where
       EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM THE ( SELECT CAST( STR2TBL( P_JOBID ) AS MYTABLETYPE ) FROM DUAL ) TT WHERE TT.COLUMN_VALUE = CR.JOBID )
       --CR.JOBID in (select REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_JOBID,'[^,]+', 1, level) from DUAL connect by REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_JOBID, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
      and CREATEDBY = P_USERNAME
        and JOBID > 0
        --ORDER BY CR.CHANGEREQUESTID DESC
      )
  WHERE ROWNO >= START_RECORD_NO AND ROWNO <= END_RECORD_NO;
  
END CHANGEREQUESTS_CREATED_GETLIST;
```

Also the table definition and required details are below

```
`CHANGEREQUESTS`

Name                        Null     Type           
--------------------------- -------- -------------- 
CHANGEREQUESTID             NOT NULL NUMBER(10)     
CHANGEREQUESTNUMBER         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)   
CHANGETYPEID                NOT NULL NUMBER(10)     
NETWORKTYPE                          VARCHAR2(50)   
STATENAME                            VARCHAR2(50)   
CITYNAME                             VARCHAR2(50)   
DESCRIPTION                          VARCHAR2(100)  
REASON                               VARCHAR2(250)  
REMARK                               VARCHAR2(250)  
CREATEDBY                            NVARCHAR2(100) 
CREATEDON                            DATE           
LASTMODIFIEDBY                       NVARCHAR2(100) 
LASTMODIFIEDON                       DATE           
JOBID                                NUMBER(10)     
GROUPID                              NUMBER(10)     
STATUSID                             NUMBER         
ISCANCELLED                 NOT NULL NUMBER(1)      
APPLICATIONID                        NUMBER(10)     
APPCHANGETYPE                        VARCHAR2(50)   
CHANGEDETAILID                       NUMBER(10)     
REQSUBMITTEDON                       DATE           
PRIORITY                             VARCHAR2(50)   
MODELING_CHANGE_TYPE_IDS             VARCHAR2(200)  
MODELING_CHANGE_DETAILS_IDS          VARCHAR2(200)  
DB_CHANGE_DETAIL_ID                  NUMBER(10)     
BAND                                 VARCHAR2(2000) 



`CHANGETYPES`

Name             Null     Type          
---------------- -------- ------------- 
CHANGETYPEID     NOT NULL NUMBER(10)    
CHANGETYPE       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(250) 
CHANGECATEGORYID          NUMBER(10)    
ISACTIVE         NOT NULL NUMBER(1) 


`CHANGECATEGORIES`

Name             Null     Type          
---------------- -------- ------------- 
CHANGECATEGORYID NOT NULL NUMBER(10)   
CATEGORY         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50) 
ISACTIVE         NOT NULL NUMBER(1)
```

**UPDATE**

So basically my Oracle version is:- 18.3

Also,

The above procedure consists of 3 tables in which main columns are `CHANGETYPEID`, `CHANGECATEGORYID` They have joined to bring the data.

So my main table is `CHANGEREQUESTS` where records are been fetched from joining the ID's of other two tables.

For ex:-

```sql
CREATE TABLE CHANGEREQUESTS ( CHANGEREQUESTID, CHANGETYPEID, JOBID ) AS 
SELECT 7835,  4, 42234 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7834, 22, 42233 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7833,  8, 42242 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE CHANGETYPES (CHANGETYPEID, CHANGETYPE, CHANGECATEGORYID, ISACTIVE) AS
SELECT  8, 'Change in media type (OFC/MW)', 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22, 'RF site deletion',              1, 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE CHANGECATEGORIES ( CHANGECATEGORYID, CATEGORY, ISACTIVE ) AS
SELECT 3, 'OSP Engineering', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Wireline',        1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Wireless',        1 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to have a [MRE] including: DDL statements for your tables (and remove the columns that are not necessary so there are only 5 or 6 columns per table); DML statements for some sample data (both as text we can copy/paste/execute rather than as images that are half missing); all the functions necessary to run the code (`STR2TBL`?); your expected output; and your Oracle version.

Comment: Of course it won't get 100 rows when you are filtering on `WHERE ROWNO >= START_RECORD_NO AND ROWNO <= END_RECORD_NO` when `START_RECORD_NO` is `0` (why not `1`?) and `END_RECORD_NO` is 10.

Comment: @MT0: so what should be `START_RECORD_NO` and `END_RECORD_NO` and according to you what should it come?

Comment: @MT0: I have updated the question with the relevant columns and its data in each table.. Do let me know in case if anything else is required to understand.

Comment: You're much more likely to get help if you can post a [MRE] with (as I said in the first comment) DDL/DML statements that we can copy/paste/execute (rather than as images). Please help us to help you by not expecting us to type out data that you've posted as an image. Also, give us a complete worked example (i.e. what are the parameters going in to the procedure and the expected output for your sample output).

Comment: can u come over this chat link so that I can briefly explain and give you the query and expected output. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224195/oracle-discussion

Comment: [edit] your question so everyone can answer it.

Comment: @MT0: is that OK ?? i have updated with query and sample data and with version no

Comment: Not really, the data was as text but wasn't as DDL/DML statements that can be copy/pasted/executed so work was needed getting it to a useable form. You hadn't supplied the `MYTABLETYPE` data type nor `STR2TBL` function and you hadn't given an example of the parameters you are putting into your procedure or what you would expect to get back from it. The question is about not getting enough rows of data back from the procedure and you've given 3 lines of sample data. I've given an answer but its a almost complete rewrite rather than debugging your solution as too much is missing to run yours.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your procedure a lot by:

- testing if the `jobid` is a substring of the `p_jobid` parameter; and
- using `OFFSET m ROWS FETCH NEXT n ROWS ONLY` syntax.

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE CHANGEREQUESTS_CREATED_GETLIST
(
  P_USERNAME IN CHANGEREQUESTS.CREATEDBY%type
, P_JOBID    IN CLOB--VARCHAR2
, P_PAGENO   IN NUMBER
, P_PAGESIZE IN NUMBER
, TOTALCOUNT OUT NUMBER
, OUTPUTTABLE OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
  v_size  NUMBER := COALESCE( p_pagesize, 10 );
  v_start NUMBER := COALESCE( p_pageno - 1, 0 ) * v_size;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO TOTALCOUNT 
  FROM   CHANGEREQUESTS CR
  WHERE  ',' || p_jobid || ',' LIKE '%,' || jobid || ',%'
  AND    CREATEDBY = P_USERNAME
  AND    JOBID > 0;

  OPEN OUTPUTTABLE FOR 
  SELECT CR.CHANGEREQUESTID
        ,CT.CHANGETYPE
        ,CR.JOBID
  FROM   CHANGEREQUESTS CR
         INNER JOIN CHANGETYPES CT
           ON ( CR.CHANGETYPEID = CT.CHANGETYPEID )
         INNER JOIN CHANGECATEGORIES CC
           ON ( CC.CHANGECATEGORYID = CT.CHANGECATEGORYID )
  WHERE  ',' || p_jobid || ',' LIKE '%,' || jobid || ',%'
  AND    CREATEDBY = P_USERNAME
  AND    JOBID > 0
  ORDER BY CR.CHANGEREQUESTID DESC
  OFFSET v_start ROWS
  FETCH NEXT v_size ROWS ONLY;
END CHANGEREQUESTS_CREATED_GETLIST;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CHANGEREQUESTS ( CHANGEREQUESTID, CHANGETYPEID, JOBID, CREATEDBY ) AS 
SELECT 7835,  4, 42234, 'user1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7834, 22, 42233, 'user1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7833,  8, 42242, 'user1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL,
       DECODE( MOD( LEVEL, 3), 0, 4, 1, 22, 8 ),
       99999,
       'user1'
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 40;

CREATE TABLE CHANGETYPES (CHANGETYPEID, CHANGETYPE, CHANGECATEGORYID, ISACTIVE) AS
SELECT  4, 'Random Type',                   1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 'Change in media type (OFC/MW)', 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22, 'RF site deletion',              1, 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE CHANGECATEGORIES ( CHANGECATEGORYID, CATEGORY, ISACTIVE ) AS
SELECT 3, 'OSP Engineering', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Wireline',        1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Wireless',        1 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_pgsz NUMBER := 20;
BEGIN
  FOR v_pgno IN 1 .. 3 LOOP
    DECLARE
      v_cur  SYS_REFCURSOR;
      v_size NUMBER;
      v_crid CHANGEREQUESTS.CHANGEREQUESTID%TYPE;
      v_ctyp CHANGETYPES.CHANGETYPE%TYPE;
      v_jid  CHANGEREQUESTS.JOBID%TYPE;
    BEGIN
      CHANGEREQUESTS_CREATED_GETLIST( 'user1', '42234,99999', v_pgno, v_pgsz, v_size, v_cur );
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Page:' || v_pgno || ' (Total: ' || v_size || ' rows)' );
      LOOP
        FETCH v_cur INTO v_crid, v_ctyp, v_jid;
        EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
          LPAD( v_crid,  4, ' ' ) || ' | ' ||
          RPAD( v_ctyp, 30, ' ' ) || ' | ' ||
          LPAD( v_jid,   4, ' ' )
        );
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE v_cur;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Outputs:

```
Page:1 (Total: 41 rows)
7835 | Random Type                    | 4223
  40 | RF site deletion               | 9999
  39 | Random Type                    | 9999
  38 | Change in media type (OFC/MW)  | 9999
  37 | RF site deletion               | 9999
  36 | Random Type                    | 9999
  35 | Change in media type (OFC/MW)  | 9999
  34 | RF site deletion               | 9999
  33 | Random Type                    | 9999
  32 | Change in media type (OFC/MW)  | 9999
  31 | RF site deletion               | 9999
  30 | Random Type                    | 9999
  29 | Change in media type (OFC/MW)  | 9999
  28 | RF site deletion               | 9999
  27 | Random Type                    | 9999
  26 | Change in media type (OFC/MW)  | 9999
  25 | RF site deletion               | 9999
  24 | Random Type                    | 9999
  23 | Change in media type (OFC/MW)  | 9999
  22 | RF site deletion               | 9999
Page:2 (Total: 41 rows)
  21 | Random Type                    | 9999
  20 | Change in media type (OFC/MW)  | 9999
  19 | RF site deletion               | 9999
  18 | Random Type                    | 9999
  17 | Change in media type (OFC/MW)  | 9999
  16 | RF site deletion               | 9999
  15 | Random Type                    | 9999
  14 | Change in media type (OFC/MW)  | 9999
  13 | RF site deletion               | 9999
  12 | Random Type                    | 9999
  11 | Change in media type (OFC/MW)  | 9999
  10 | RF site deletion               | 9999
   9 | Random Type                    | 9999
   8 | Change in media type (OFC/MW)  | 9999
   7 | RF site deletion               | 9999
   6 | Random Type                    | 9999
   5 | Change in media type (OFC/MW)  | 9999
   4 | RF site deletion               | 9999
   3 | Random Type                    | 9999
   2 | Change in media type (OFC/MW)  | 9999
Page:3 (Total: 41 rows)
   1 | RF site deletion               | 9999
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=06a6eaea0acc66c348e17acd5d194e96)*

Comment: @hud I am using exactly what is in the answer. There is only 1 procedure and then there is an anonymous PL/SQL block that calls the procedure in a loop for pages 1, 2, and then 3 and displays the output. You can check the db<>fiddle link at the bottom to see it running. You don't need that anonymous PL/SQL block, its just there to demonstrate calling the function.

Comment: @hud The linked db<>fiddle has the procedure running without errors (in Oracle 18); please go through line-by-line and check that you have the syntax correct because you have something different from my code (which is running without errors).

Comment: i am using this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9173f399274c30df18bb46d32602b209 and its giving me error. Dont understand what i am missing

Comment: It almost certainly will work in Oracle 19 as Oracle is compatible with prior versions. However, db<>fiddle only provides environments for Oracle 11gR2 and Oracle 18. If you want to test it on Oracle 19 then you will either need your own local environment with that version or to go to https://livesql.oracle.com and run it there.

Comment: You need a `/` at the end (to show it is PL/SQL) and you haven't created the tables so it doesn't understand `CHANGEREQUESTS.CREATEDBY%type`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0cde8af627fc41ab7db81e0e60c66184)

Comment: Please look at the db<>fiddle in the previous comment. It works through fixing the first couple of errors and getting the error messages to tell you what your next problem is .... however, all the errors relate to that missing trailing `/` (which must be on a line of its own after the end of the procedure) and that you are missing the tables.

Comment: As I [said on the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64679290/64715056?comment114424061_64679290), if you want to know why it isn't working for `changetypeid = 8` then you have to give us a [MRE] with all the sample data where you demonstrate how it doesn't work .... we can't help you fix a problem that we cannot see.